# How to split One letter away from a string in python

Tags: python

I am working on a little command program for fun and was wondering how to split only the first letter for the command to call the command. Here is the code I already have:

```
command = input(" ")
commandCheck = command.split("!",2) # ! is the command caller
print(commandCheck)
```

I haven't really learned how to split only one letter from the rest of the list and whenever I run this code it seems to delete the first letter for example if I input "!Work" it outputs

```
['', 'work']
Press any key to continue . . .`
```

but I want the exclamation mark in between the spaces of the first object in the list if that makes any sense. like,

```
['!','work']
```

If you know the correct syntax or something to help plz tell me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the expected output? please edit the question to include expected output

Comment: `['!', 'work']` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can just get the index of the letter with:

```
exclamation_pos = my_string.index("!")
```

And get the parts with:

```
[my_string[:exclamation_pos+1], my_string[exclamation_pos+1:]]
```

This should output what you expect:

```
["!", "work"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do partition instead of split if you want the `!` mark also. The below code should do the trick.

```
command = '!work'
commandCheck = filter(None, command.partition('!'))
print commandCheck
```